# How to define and use geo points in sequelize with mySQL

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm using sequelize ORM to connect to a MYSQL database - how would I define a geo POINT in the table/object model?  Since sequelize doesn't have a POINT data type can I just pass in a string that represents a MYSQL type?

```
db.define(modelName, {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false
    },
    location:{
        type:'POINT' //how would I define this??
    },
    createdBy: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: {
            model: 'User',
            key: 'id'
        }
    },
    photoId: {
        type: Sequelize.UUID
    },
    caption: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Since 3.4.0 Sequelize support geometry for postgres. Based on commit messages, MySQL is also supported.

You can add new attribute like this:

```
point: {
   type: Sequelize.GEOMETRY('POINT'),
},
```

The supported [types](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/75b2503ac6609a7a07bd0fbc6edc19e1681c802b/lib/dialects/mysql/data-types.js#L19) for MySQL are:

```
var SUPPORTED_GEOMETRY_TYPES = ['POINT', 'LINESTRING', 'POLYGON'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create it through `STRING` and create a custom `toJSON` implementation on the instance so you can get a `POINT` you want.

[Data Types](http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/models-definition/#data-types)
[Instance methods](http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/models-definition/#expansion-of-models)

On those instance methods you can define also a `toJSON` custom method which will be automatically called when sending the object through `res.send(obj)`

Comment: I would need to store it as a POINT type in the mysql database as well and not as a string - to take advantage of geo spatial indexes.  Would this technique store it as a native point in my sql or would toJSON just render the point in the way I want in the output?

Comment: Don't think so, I'd recommend you to add an issue as a feature request on Sequelize repo, or create a PR to support that kind of Data Type

Comment: Looks like there is a pull request already https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/3828